# C# date formatting is losing slash separators

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

If I do this in C#:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd M/dd/yy"));
```

I would expect output like this:

```
Wed 6/15/11
```

But it actually outputs this:

```
Wed 6 15 11
```

Why are the slashes disappearing? Is there a way to prevent this and have the date outputted in the expected format?

Comment: I get the slashes with your format string. What is the culture you are running under?

Comment: I copied your code and ran it with Snippet Compiler.  It output 'Wed 6/15/11'.

Comment: This issue only appears to happen in Windows 7 when you change your short date format to "ddd M/dd/yy".

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows 7 and everything to do with the _Culture_ you are running the program under.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this using string.Format()?  The slashes are replaced when I use `string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt}", myDate)` and `string.Format("{0:G}", myDate)`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd M/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

try the above

Comment: This appears to work, why is the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture required here?

Comment: @Jon - Because if a `CultureInfo` is not specified, the current culture will be used. If this is a culture that doesn't use slashes as separators in dates (and the format string specifies the date separator to be a `/`, that is replaced by whatever the actual culture date separator is).

Comment: based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx I would assume that it appears that your cultureinfo is changing the "/" to " "

Comment: My Default culture considers dash as default date separator, even if Region Format to set to uses slash "/"  as default date separator, which is English (US). Am I missing anything ? Please suggest
I am using windows 11, Timezone IST +5:30.

Answer (score 38):

The default behavior of the "/" (slash) in a format argument is to use the current's culture date separator.

To force the "/" (slash), you must precede it with a "\" (backslash).

Ex.: "yyyy\\/MM\\/dd" will always display a date like "2015/07/02" independent of the current culture in use.

Comment: Very nice detail :) using your solution in conjunction with "Culture.Invariant" will guarantee at 100% that your date has the exact format that you specified :)

Answer (score 32):

You could also use

```
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("ddd M'/'dd'/'yy"));
```

That's a possible solution if you're not using the invariant culture as mentioned in other answers here.

Comment: Thanks! This fixes windows region settings too. https://imgur.com/a/8j8aLik