# Converting DateTime to string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to convert `DateTime` to `String`.

check the below code.

```
namespace TestDateConvertion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object value = new DateTime(2003,12,23,6,22,30);
            DateTime result = (DateTime)value;
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed my system date format to Faeroese.

and I am getting the output as

> 23-12-2013

How should I get the output as ?

> 23/12/2013

And consider this another scenario,
suppose, i have a Customculture Info , and i want to convert my date w.r.t my custom culture,
what i was doing before was as follows,

```
string.Format(customCulture, "{0:G}", result);
```

now how shall i get the datetime in string using customCulture and it should not depend on system DateTime?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362088/c-sharp-date-formatting-is-losing-slash-separators

Comment: Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd M/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Console.ReadLine(); from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362088/c-sharp-date-formatting-is-losing-slash-separators

Comment: `/` has a special meaning of "replace me with the current culture's date separator". You can enforce it with passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter.

Comment: There was an answer from user oleksiiless [which seems to be correct](http://ideone.com/ab37qm) (AFAIKT). But it was downvoted and i assume this was the reason for the author to delete it. Could someone take a look if i set the culture in the right way to verify that `now.ToShortDateString()` is enough to ouptput the date as required?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like your culture's date separator is `-` and as Tim [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526239/converting-datetime-to-string#comment25485437_17526239), `/` replaces itself with it.

You should use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) as a second parameter in your `result.ToString()` method.

> Gets the CultureInfo object that is **culture-independent** (invariant).

```
object value = new DateTime(2003, 12, 23, 6, 22, 30);
DateTime result = (DateTime)value;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
23/12/2003
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/HCGjYx).

Comment: Cool i did not know about [ideone](http://ideone.com/0ZU9Wg)

Comment: @Soner Gönül, thanks for introducing to http://ideone.com/

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree and Satpal, you are welcome guys. Ideone is really great tool for posting code examples on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: If your format, all specifiers are wrong. `ddd` is for abbreviated names for example..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this

```
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Now your Code becomes

```
object value = new DateTime(2003, 12, 23, 6, 22, 30);
DateTime result = (DateTime)value;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.ReadLine();
```

**NOTE**
**Add  using System.Globalization;**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the invariant culture:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",result)
```

Good luck

Wing

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Tim Schmelter's comment and Soner Gönül's answer. Just wanted to add that when you are using Date Time format you should specify culture because by default culture will be get from `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (culture set in `Control Panel->Region and Languages->Format`), that means that with different settings your input will be different.

Take a look on your example with different cultures:

```
object value = new DateTime(2003, 12, 23, 6, 22, 30);
DateTime result = (DateTime)value;
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
       Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", culture));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'/' is a special char that means "regional settings date separator". if you want use it like a normal char you can quote it using the quoter chart '\'
Example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")
```