# TryParseExact returns false, though I don't know why

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

Method  `TryParseExact` in code block below returns `true`.
I would like to know why.
I think this date `"2013.03.12"` is invalid because this is not separated by slash but dot.

After I changed the `CultureInfo` `"de-De"` to `"en-US"`, the method returns `false`. This could be a hint but I still don't know why this happens.

```
var format = new string[] { "yyyy/MM/dd" };
var parsed = new DateTime();
var result = DateTime.TryParseExact("2013.03.12", format, 
             new CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed);
```

Comment: BTW: `2013.03.12` is not a valid/usual German date format. `12.03.2013` would be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your current [`DateSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator)  is `.` (dot) and `/` automatically replace itself to it.

`/` separator has a special meaning of "*replace me with the current culture's date separator*".

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator); //Prints . (dot)
```

Take a look at [the `"/"` Custom Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator).

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yeah, I wasn't aware of this either since Tim Schmelter [points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526239/converting-datetime-to-string/17526314#comment25485437_17526239) this situation almost a month ago.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes, I don't have to define formats by country in this specification.

Answer (score 7):

As @Soner Gönül [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350342/15498), the `/` is taken as "the date separator" in [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator). If you want to only accept `/` characters, you need to escape them:

```
var format = new string[] { @"yyyy\/MM\/dd" };
```

Comment: A @ please before the "