# When setting Culture, can I override the date format to e.g. mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

When I set the CurrentCulture, how can I override the date format that is set?

Example:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Say I wanted to override the default date format so whenever I output DateTime value it is by default in the format I want.

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to create an instance of `CultureInfo` that won't be read only. Then you can create an instance of your `DateTimeFormatInfo`, configure it appropriately and finally assign it to your `CultureInfo` object:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
//or simply var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
//then for example: 
dateformat.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

The full specification on how to configure your DateTimeFormatInfo can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Comment: This won't work.  `GetCultureInfo` returns a read-only CultureInfo object.

Comment: Excellent, I was looking for this comment for long time !

Comment: This is good answer and totally working, Pawel Bejger, cool guy.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` doesn't have *format*. Strings have. Sounds like you just need to use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime.ToString("mm\/dd\/yyyy", culture);
```

Rememer [`The "/" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning. If you want only `/` character, you should escape it. Take a look at my another *[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350342/447156)*.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` returns a [cached, read-only version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you can do is format a DateTime like you normally would, or create your own Culture, inheriting the behavior of your desired culture.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `ToString()` method on `DateTime`:

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

There are many, many ways to format dates with patterns. Here is a reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx