# Convert String to DateTime with pattern "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a string variable containing `"02/27/2014 23:00:28"`
When I use this following code to convert it to `Datetime` type, the conversion fails (test returns false and `parsedDate` contains `"01/01/0001 00:00:00"`)

code:

```
string date = "02/27/2014 23:00:28"
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
DateTime parsedDate;
bool parsedSuccessfully = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

Thank you!

Comment: BTW I guess you would wanna send the `date` variable into `DateTime.TryParseExact` method, not the `test` itself =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use uppercase `HH` for the hours since you are using 24h format.

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

You also need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` to ensure that `/` will be used as date separator. Otherwise it is replaced by your cultures actual date separator. *

```
bool test = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

- [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) *

Answer (score 3):

[`hh` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for `01` to `12`.

Use [`HH` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) which is for `00` to `23`. (*24-hour clock based*)

And I think you should use `date` instead of `test` in your [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string date = "02/27/2014 23:00:28";
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime parsedDate;
bool test= DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern,
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
Console.WriteLine(test); // True
```

Since you using `null` in your [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter, it uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> If provider is null, the `CultureInfo` object that corresponds to the
>   current culture is used.

But [`/ format specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of "*replace me with the current culture date seperator*" in your string format.

That means, if your current culture's date separator is not `/`, your parsing operation will be fail. That's why you should use `InvariantCulture` in such a case.

Here an another answer: [TryParseExact returns false, though I don't know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350301/tryparseexact-returns-false-though-i-dont-know-why/18350342#18350342)

Answer (score 2):

24-hour time format uses `HH`. So your format should be

```
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```