# String Format of Date in CheckBox Content

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I have a `CheckBox` that I want to say;

> "Load Prior to: 01/01/2001"

But instead the content says;

> "Load Prior to: 01 01 2001"

Basically there are no *slashes*. This is my how I set the content;

```
oldContactsCheckBox.Content = 
  "Load Contracts Prior To: " + 
   DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

How can I change this so that the slashes are included in the formatting?

Comment: This [Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362088/c-sharp-date-formatting-is-losing-slash-separators) is your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *escaping*:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#escape

```
oldContactsCheckBox.Content = 
  "Load Contracts Prior To: " + 
  DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3).ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

A better implementation is *string interpolation* (C# 6.0):

```
oldContactsCheckBox.Content = 
  $@"Load Contracts Prior To: {DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3):dd\/MM\/yyyy}";
```

or *formatting*:

```
oldContactsCheckBox.Content = string.Format(
  @"Load Contracts Prior To: {0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}",
    DateTime.Today.AddYears(-3));
```

Comment: Note that string interpolation is only available from C#6